# Clear contents of every 4 adjacent cells if one of them contains a date

Tags: vba, excel

In a range (I3:CD161), I have repeating sets of 4 columns with headers: (item name, cost, retail, date sold).  I need to go thru every set to clear the contents of all 4 contiguous cells (under 'item name', 'cost', 'retail', 'date sold') each time a date entry is present in every 'date sold' column. I tried to attach a screen shot here but it won't allow.  So, I placed a link to it instead. Please have a look below.

[image]

In the screen cap, please note that the red cell colors and strikethroughs are from conditional formatting. Which means it is too complex for me to find cells by color and then clear the contents.  This is why I would rather search every 'date sold' column > find all cells with date entries > offset 3 more cells to the left > clear contents of these 4 adjacent cells (including date) > move on thru all of range (I3:CD161).  I hope this makes sense.

Your kind assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tested working solution for finding a certain date and clearing the contents of cells three, two, and one to the left of it (including itself).  Will cycle through whole sheet to check.

```
Sub TestIt()

Dim Rng As Range, DateToFind As Date

DateToFind = InputBox("Enter the date to find", "Enter Date", "mm/dd/yyy")

Do
    Set Rng = Cells.Find(DateToFind, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Range(Rng.Offset(0, -3), Rng).ClearContents
Loop Until Rng Is Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will search for a whole year:

```
Sub TestIt()

Dim Rng As Range, YearToFind As Integer

YearToFind = InputBox("Enter the year to find", "Enter Year", "yyyy")

For Each Rng in ActiveSheet.Cells 'I'd recommend making this search range smaller as Cells searches whole sheet
    If Year(Rng.Value) = YearToFind Then Range(Rng.Offset(0, -3), Rng).ClearContents
Next Rng

End Sub
```